# Understanding proof of variance of mean of random effects model and relationship to E[MS_treatments]

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, anova, variance

My textbook makes the following proof:

[image]

But I cannot understand how it arrives.

The variance of $y_{ij} = \sigma^2 + \sigma_t^2$ by assumption
this leads to:

$MS_e = \sigma^2$
$MS_{treatments} = \sigma^2 + n\sigma_t^2$

But it seems like we're instead simply finding:

$Var(\bar{y}) = \frac{Var(SS_{total})}{a^2n^2}$ based on the above equation.

I don't understand how it relates back to MStreatments or even how putting MStreatments in the numerator would resolve the variance derivation, since the denominator would be squared.

Is the idea that the MS_treatments can be broken into two sums and then the term of for the treatment variance can be divided by n to arrive at the variance of y_ij?

Can you help me understand this proof please?

If the images are not OK let me know I will remove and write the textbook explanation out.